# Why is the Turf Javascript library's 'transformTranslate' function distorting geometries?

Tags: mapbox, turf

I'm working on a webapp using [MapBoxGL](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) and [TurfJS](http://turfjs.org/docs/) and I've encountered an issue using Turf's `transformTranslate`, which is [defined here](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/tree/master/packages/turf-transform-translate).

Now, the issue is that a geometry that is being transformed is getting distorted.

For example, this is the original geometry:

[image: Original geometry]

And this is the translated geometry:

[image: Translated geometry]

And the relevant section of code is this:

```js
  console.log(typology)

  var typologyCentroid = centroid(typology)
  var mapCenter = this.$store.state.map.getCenter()
  var mapCenterToTurf = lngLatToTurfPoint(mapCenter)

  var typologyDistToMapCenter = rhumbDistance(typologyCentroid, mapCenterToTurf)
  var typologyBearingToMapCenter = rhumbBearing(typologyCentroid, mapCenterToTurf)

  var translatedPoly = transformTranslate(typology, typologyDistToMapCenter, typologyBearingToMapCenter)

  console.log(translatedPoly)
```

The actual goal is to get a feature and shift it to be in the centre of the current map display. I can't understand why the translate is twisting and distorting the feature though.

Edit: it turns out that I can achieve what I want by just using a simple shift (adding deltaX and deltaY to each coordinate). I'm surprised that the Turf function doesn't work as expected, though... I'm leaving the question up.

Comment: How well do you know the theory of the Rhumb line https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhumb_line? I don't know that at all but I just wonder if it if something more complex than the simple shift and perhaps it is correct that the shape is changing.

Comment: Hey @user30184. I did look at the source, and can see that the translation is based on some pretty serious geodesy! I guess that I'd assume some changes to the object's shape, but, if you represent a square building in on place on the earth, it should still be a square building somewhere else, I would have thought. And it isn't projection based, because in this case it's a shift in longitude, mostly. Plus the images above are displayed in Lat/Lon...

Comment: Did you make the move in kilometers or by decrees and is your map using the same units? It could be that each vertex of the polygon is moved individually and the fact that longitudes are shorter closer to the poles may have a role here. Is the result the same if you convert the corners of the buildings as a set of points?

Comment: How do you calculate the shifts (delta values)?

Comment: It's there in the example code, @RodrigoGauzmanf